# How insert a LinearLayout between AppBarLayout and the scrolling content, when using CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm using a CoordinatorLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout. I'm trying to put a LinearLayout below AppBarLayout and above the scrolling content, and I want that this LinearLayout stays always fixed on the screen (with AppBarLayout hidden or not), not scrolling with the content.

Is this possible?

So far, I have the following code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    tools:context="..."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagemView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/back_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/back_button"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="18dp"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="myBehavior"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: add it in CollapsingToolbarLayout or Scrollview.

Comment: Tried both, but didn't work like I wanted. In CollapsingToolbarLayout the LinearLayout cover part of the image, and in Scrollview, the LinearLayout scrolls together, and I want that it stays fixed on screen.

Comment: int CollapsingToolbarLayout set LinearLayout  gravity to bottom and set Image marginbottom  to LinearLayout‘height.

Answer (score 5):

So far I got this by following:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout/>//Layout which will stay between CollapsingToolbarLayout and Recyler or nested scroll view

    <Recycler Or Nested Scroll View/>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here Linear layout will scroll but it will always be visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve that with this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagemView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/back_button"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="18dp"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and then include

```
<include
    layout="@layout/content_scrolling"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

No need to set any scroll flag to the LinearLayout so the CoordinatorLayout will only hide the CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: It almost worked. Indeed, the LinearLayout stayed where I wanted, but behind the scrolling content.